# In-app language switching not working in android app bundle with enableSplit=false

Tags: android, gradle, multilingual, android-app-bundle

I am publishing an using the Android app Bundle. I don't have time to implement the PlayCore API to download languages on demand so I just added this to the **base** module, so there won't be any language splitting in the bundles:

```
android {
    bundle {
        language {
            enableSplit = false
        }
    }
}
```

The APK size did get larger, but changing languages in-app now doesn't cause the change (except in **one** fragment, which extends PreferenceFragmentCompat)

Furthermore, I also have a **library** module (`apply plugin: 'com.android.library'`) and when I try to add the above code to it I get

> > Could not find method bundle() for arguments [build_ck0w3ieqon7ta3tuog615zy8h$_run_closure1$_closure7@219c4533] on
> >     object of type com.android.build.gradle.LibraryExtension.

I can't think of any other reason why the in-app language change won't work in an Android App Bundle now, when it worked in an APK. Any ideas?

Comment: Mine doesn't work with APK neither even though it was. I sent the API to testers via Firebase Distribution and today he said the app couldn't change the language...